# How to count the invocation of Webservices deployed on Glassfish 3.1

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

How to count the  invocation  of Webservices deployed on Glassfish 3.1?
Actually I can get what I want at console commands? as following

```
asadmin get -m "server.applications.hello-jaxws2*" server.applications.hello-jaxws2.2.server.Hello.requestcount-count = 14
```

But I want to know if there is a way of getting the invocation count of web services programatically?

Comment: You can use the Glassfish MBeans via the JMX API. But if you are in are cluster scenario, you would need to address that at the application level or have a monitoring tool that handles that for you.

Comment: I have nearly overviewed all of the objectNames at MBeans but I have only found list of the name of webservices but invocation count. If you know the objectName that addresses the invocation count , it will appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example using Glassfish 3.1.2. and a Web service named "NewWebService" here is a code extract that retrieves the number of requests for that Web service.

```
public static void showRequestCount(MBeanServerConnection mbs) throws Exception {
    ObjectName on = new ObjectName("amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=servlet-instance-mon,name=WebApplication1/server/NewWebService");
    final Set<ObjectInstance> mBeans = mbs.queryMBeans(on, null);
    for (ObjectInstance mbean : mBeans) {
        System.out.println("mbean: " + mbean);
        final MBeanInfo info = mbs.getMBeanInfo(on);
        final MBeanAttributeInfo[] attributes = info.getAttributes();
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
            MBeanAttributeInfo mBeanAttributeInfo = attributes[i];
            if (mBeanAttributeInfo.getName().equals("requestcount")) {
                final Object attribute = mbs.getAttribute(on, mBeanAttributeInfo.getName());
                CompositeDataSupport cds = (CompositeDataSupport) attribute;
                final Object requestCount = cds.get("count");
                System.out.println("Object name: " + on.getKeyProperty("name"));
                System.out.println("Request count: " + requestCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
mbean: servlet-instance-mon[amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=servlet-instance-mon,name=WebApplication1/server/NewWebService]
Object name: WebApplication1/server/NewWebService
Request count: 18
```

Please note that the ObjectName of the MBean and/or its attributes may vary depending on your Glassfish version.

Comment: I cannot get list of ObjectNames using  amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=servlet-instance-mon,name=* but I cna get list of object names via amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=WSEndpoint,name=*. What could be wrong?

Comment: This is a new question: getting the list of Glassfish MBeans with their object names.

Comment: I am using amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=servlet-instance-mon,name=CalculatorApp/server/CalculatorWS as an object name, I have copied this name from jconsole (servlet-instance-mon). But I get final Set<ObjectInstance> mBeans EMPTY

Comment: restarting application server solves the problem as usual. Thanks.

Comment: One more things, Have you ever deployed the webservice on any cluster and its instances, then check "sevleet-instance-mon" tab on jconsole? I have tested it that there is not any webservice like <webserviceName>Instance1<xxx> but <webserviceName>server<xxx>

Comment: I have found out away of monitoring cluster instances that If you consfigure cluster1-conf for JMX connections instead of server-conf, you can find a menu for each instance of the cluster and webservices installed them.